# Why did I get an 'using an untrusted daemon' warning?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, privacy, daemon

I'm running a full node and I followed every security step to set up the node on my computer. Everything was going great until today when I realized that a view-only wallet created the day before was finishing the refresh process from 0 blockchain height and showing a warning message:

```
Warning: using an untrusted daemon at localhost:18081, privacy will be lessened.
```

In monerod, everything looks fine, and the port that is used is not `18081`.

I waited all night long the refresh process and now I don't know if my privacy is indeed lessened because of it or not.

Is this a *"standard warning"* to everyone that goes through the process of refreshing a new wallet or does this actually mean that daemon at `localhost:18081`, and not the daemon from my computer was used to refresh the wallet?

Comment: Did you run `monerod` with `--bind-ip`?

Comment: How are you starting the daemon and with what settings? What settings are you using in the GUI or wallet-cli?

Comment: "Port used is not 18081". Which port did you use? Which command did you use to run the monero daemon?